# MySQL: How do I exclude certain dates from my query?

Tags: mysql

Reports due for December 2015 are being generated in January 2016. There are already entries made for January 2016. How do I exclude January 2016 from December 2015:

My query:

```
SELECT historyid, h.attend_date, h.amount_paid, p.groupdate, h.clientid, p.clientid
FROM history AS h
INNER JOIN participation AS p on p.clientid = h.clientid
WHERE h.clientid = 1
AND attend_date = groupdate
ORDER BY attend_date ASC,
historyid DESC
```

That query provides:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+
| historyid | attend_date | amount_paid | groupdate  | clientid | clientid |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+
|        52 | 2015-12-06  |          60 | 2015-12-06 |        1 |        1 |
|        56 | 2015-12-07  |          60 | 2015-12-07 |        1 |        1 |
|        60 | 2015-12-08  |          60 | 2015-12-08 |        1 |        1 |
|        65 | 2015-12-09  |          15 | 2015-12-09 |        1 |        1 |
|        78 | 2016-01-01  |          15 | 2016-01-01 |        1 |        1 |
|        83 | 2016-01-02  |          15 | 2016-01-02 |        1 |        1 |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

How do I retrieve only the rows for December 2015?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT historyid, h.attend_date, h.amount_paid, p.groupdate, h.clientid, p.clientid 
FROM history AS h 
INNER JOIN participation AS p on p.clientid = h.clientid 
WHERE h.clientid = 1 
AND attend_date = groupdate 
AND MONTH(attend_date) = 12 
AND YEAR(attend_date) = 2015 
ORDER BY attend_date ASC, historyid DESC
```

Comment: This way it will only retrieve data that you want to

Comment: I like your answer. With the way I have this page setup, I believe your solution will work best. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Add a date range to limit your query:

```
SELECT historyid, h.attend_date, h.amount_paid, p.groupdate, h.clientid, p.clientid
FROM history AS h
INNER JOIN participation AS p on p.clientid = h.clientid
WHERE h.clientid = 1
AND attend_date = groupdate
AND attend_date < '2016-01-01'
AND attend_date >= '2015-12-01'
ORDER BY attend_date ASC,
historyid DESC
```

and it will only grab rows before the start of this year and in the month of December of last year.

Comment: Let's say there are entries for every month of 2015. How wld I pinpoint Dec 2015 only?

Comment: This will all have to be done programmatically, and I think I can work with your solution just fine, inserting variables in those checkpoints.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions for this.

One involves the `NOT IN` statement to determine a range of bad values. In this case 2016.

The table only has values listed for December 2015 and January 2016. So this query should return only those from December.

```
SELECT historyid, h.attend_date, h.amount_paid, p.groupdate, h.clientid, p.clientid
FROM history AS h
INNER JOIN participation AS p on p.clientid = h.clientid
WHERE h.clientid = 1
AND attend_date = groupdate
AND YEAR(attend_date) NOT IN (2016) 
ORDER BY attend_date ASC,
historyid DESC
```

But there are multiple other ways that will arrive at the exact same answer.

Comment: and to add to that: `AND MONTH IN (12)` or wld that be `AND MONTH IN (December)`?

Comment: You are right. In mysql, Month returns a number from 1 to 12. You could use month in the IN clause as well

Comment: I appreciate you, Richard. Your way is much like Guilherme Lopes'. And I think this is the best way for me. Many thanks.

Comment: I upvoted your solution. No idea why it's down. If you want to edit your answer, I'll upvote it again.